# why does the after function in tkinter have more delay than actual seconds

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a gui program that uses a timer, so i use the after function to loop the function again and again, but with a delay of 1 millisecond. But i compared it with an actual timer in google and its slightly off, just by like 50 ms/secs or so. Why is this happening and how do i prevent it?

```
global timerState
timerState = True

def pause():
    timerLabel.after_cancel(tim)
    timerState = False
    timerButton.config(text="Play", command=countdown)


def countdown():
    global t
    global tim
    

    if t == 0:
        timer = "00:00"
        timerLabel.config(text=timer)
        return

    if timerState == False:
        return

    mins = t / 60000

    secs = t / 1000
    secs = secs - int(mins) * 60

    mills = t

    mills = mills - int(secs) * 1000



    if timerState == True:
        timer = "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(int(mins),int(secs))
        timerLabel.config(text=timer)
        t -= 1
        tim = timerLabel.after(1, countdown)

        timerButton.config(text="Pause", command=pause)
```

Comment: Running stuff inside `countdown()` takes time.

Comment: You can't get timer messages with millisecond granularity.  Timers like this are only evaluated when another thread finishes its timeslice and the scheduler re-evaluates priorities.  Depending on the operating system, that can be 10ms, 16ms, or even more.  So, if you ask for a 1ms callback, you'll probably get a 16ms callback.

Comment: okay... so is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: The Python standard library has functions in its "time" module that will help to do what you want.  Others have explained that after() produces a DELAY, which is (1) not accurate, (2) gets added to the overhead of executing the rest of your code, and (3) doesn't work anyway because the OS is multi-threaded so your program will be interrupted by other applications.  Instead, display the known time of day from the time module.  If you need to wait until the next update to the user, calculate how long you want to wait and pass that number as an argument to after().

Comment: Can you give an example please? Because I don't really have a deep understanding in the time module. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simply how it is designed to work. Tkinter was never designed to be a real-time system. Tkinter runs all of its code in a single thread. If the time has elapsed and tkinter is busy doing other things (running a function, updating the screen, etc), it will have to finish what it is doing before running the scheduled function.

All of the code that you run with `after` takes time. It takes time to do math, it takes time to update labels, even the act of calling `after` takes time. When you add up all of the time it takes to do those things it can easily exceed 1ms.

Comment: Alright, thanks! But I really want it to match with a real timer, is there a way to bypass this, or another solution to make this timer accurate? Thanks again!

Comment: I found a function called ```time.sleep()```, I tried this and the results are weird. The whole page doesn't seem to run, until I use Ctrl+c which is keyboardInterrupt.

Comment: @DaveWilson: you are correct about `time.sleep()`. It does exactly what it says, it puts the entire program to sleep. That means it can't do _any_ processing, such as updating the window or responding to events.

Comment: so how can you make ```time.sleep()``` only affect a certain part of the program?

Comment: or are there other ways?

Comment: Also is there any way I can make after accurate?

Comment: @DaveWilson Look at `time.perf_counter()`.

Answer (score 1):

Further to @BryanOakley's answer a solution using `time.perf_counter()` to keep accurate time:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import time

t = 60000

def pause():
    # Use the global variable to singnal to the loop that we have paused:
    global timerState
    timerState = False
    # Change the text and command of the button
    timerButton.config(text="Play", command=start_countdown)

def start_countdown():
    global timerState, last_time
    # Use the global variable to singnal to the loop that we have started again:
    timerState = True
    timerButton.config(text="Pause", command=pause)
    last_time = time.perf_counter()
    # Start the tkinter loop again
    countdown()

def countdown():
    global t, last_time

    # Please note: `time_taken` is in seconds
    time_taken = time.perf_counter() - last_time
    last_time = time.perf_counter()

    # If the timer is paused
    if timerState:
        # Calculate and show the time
        mins = int(t // 60000)
        secs = int(t / 1000 - mins * 60)
        timerLabel.config(text=f"{str(mins).zfill(2)}:{str(secs).zfill(2)}")

        # Subtract the time since this function was last called:
        t -= time_taken * 1000

        # If there is still time on the clock
        if t > 0:
            # Call `countdown` again in 100 ms
            timerLabel.after(100, countdown)
        else:
            # Show `00:00`
            timerLabel.config(text="00:00")


root = tk.Tk()

timerLabel = tk.Label(root, text="")
timerLabel.pack()

timerButton = tk.Button(root, text="Play", command=start_countdown)
timerButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I defined 2 variables:

- `last_time` is the time stamp of the last time we called `countdown()`.
- `time_taken` is the time taken since we last called `countdown()`.

Also please note that `time.perf_counter()` is in seconds. For more info please read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for mentioning the ```time.perf_counter()``` function.